# .Net core JWT Custom Expired Token Response

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt

I have configured my web API to work with JWT and one time refresh tokens.

However I would like to modify the standard JWT middle-ware to response back to my clients who have expired tokens with HTTP 200 with a response header instead of the standard HTTP 401 response.

I have added this code the to  services.AddAuthentication() startup config.

```
            services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>
            {
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    NameClaimType = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier",
                    ValidateAudience = false,
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Tokens:Key"])),
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero //the default for this setting is 5 minutes
                };
                options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                {
                    OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
                    {
                        if (context.Exception.GetType() == typeof(SecurityTokenExpiredException))
                        {
                            context.Response.Headers.Add("Token-Expired", "True");
                            context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
                        }
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                };
            });
```

However the response back to a client is still HTTP 401. So am I missing something?

Comment: Stick a breakpoint here: context.Response.Headers.Add("Token-Expired", "True");
and check if there is another header already reporting the failure in the response. If so, remove it before adding yours

Comment: See the responses to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64082588/asp-core-api-custom-unauthorized-body

Answer (score 0):

Returning Task.Completed does not necessarily end the middleware pipelines. It keeps on going where it eventually hits the app.UseMvc() which would set the status code to 401.

What you need to is shortcircuit the pipeline after the app.UseAuthentication() pipeline but before the app.UseMvc();

Here is the middleware code:

```
    public class ExpiredTokenMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public ExpiredTokenMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            if (context.Response.Headers["Token-Expired"] == "True")
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = 200;

                // DO NOT CALL NEXT. THIS SHORTCIRCUITS THE PIPELINE
            }
            else
            {
                await _next(context);
            }
        }
    }
```

Then insert the middleware in your startup.cs between the two.

```
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseMiddleware<ExpiredTokenMiddleware>();
        app.UseMvc();
```