# ASP Core API - Custom Unauthorized body

Tags: http, asp.net-core, .net-core, httpresponse, unauthorized

I'm developing ASP Core Web API using `dotnet core` v3.1.

I'm using JWT tokens for authentication. And for authorization I use the `[Authorize]` attribute.

How can I create my own response if the user is not logged in (while trying to access the action marked with the `[Authorize]` attribute) or the user's token is not authenticated.

I came across a solution using a custom authorization attribute inherited from the default one. And in this example, the `HandleUnauthorizedRequest` method is overridden. But I don't see such a method inside the `AuthorizeAttribute` class.

Is there a way to create custom `unauthorized` responses with http body?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Since you are using JWT bearer authentication, one way to override the default Challenge logic (which executes to handle 401 Unauthorized concerns) is to hook a handler to the `JwtBearerEvents.OnChallenge` callback in `Startup.ConfigureServices`:

```cs
services.AddAuthentication().AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    // Other configs...
    options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
    {
        OnChallenge = async context =>
        {
            // Call this to skip the default logic and avoid using the default response
            context.HandleResponse();

            // Write to the response in any way you wish
            context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
            context.Response.Headers.Append("my-custom-header", "custom-value");
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("You are not authorized! (or some other custom message)");
        }
    };
});
```

This will override the default challenge logic in `JwtBearerHandler.HandleChallengeAsync`, which you can find [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/d12868dd7c10ff0433c16b06d3b59d03c40d987a/src/Security/Authentication/JwtBearer/src/JwtBearerHandler.cs#L195) for reference purposes.

The default logic does not write any content to response (it only sets the status code and set some headers). So to keep using the default logic and add content on top of it, you can use something like this:

```cs
options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
{
    OnChallenge = context =>
    {
        context.Response.OnStarting(async () =>
        {
            // Write to the response in any way you wish
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("You are not authorized! (or some other custom message)");
        });

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
};
```

Comment: Is there a way to get the response generated by the default implementation and add the http body to it?
I just want the response to have a JSON body: {success: false, errorMessage: "Not authorized"} if authentication fails.

Comment: @catman0745 The default implementation does not write any content. It only sets the response code and some headers. Please see the edited answer.

Comment: Thank you! That was really helpful

Comment: Not work!
I get :
Response headers
 content-length: 0 
 date: Thu19 Aug 2021 12:58:51 GMT 
 server: Kestrel 
 www-authenticate: Bearer

Comment: Any way to do it on a single controller and not the whole application?

Answer (score 5):

For **.net core 5 web api project** with **jwt** authentication use this middleware in Configure method of Startup.cs for show ErrorDto in **Swagger**:

```csharp
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "LoginService v1"));
    }

    app.ConfigureExceptionHandler();
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseRouting();
        
    // Unauthorized (401) MiddleWare
    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        await next();
     
        if (context.Response.StatusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized) // 401
        {
            context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
            await context.Response.WriteAsync(new ErrorDto()
            {
                StatusCode = 401,
                Message = "Token is not valid"
            }.ToString());
        }
    });

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
}
```

ErrorDto :

```csharp
public class ErrorDto
{
    public int StatusCode { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return JsonSerializer.Serialize(this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is what I came up with for responding with the same `ProblemDetails` you would get from returning `Unauthorized()` in an `ApiController`:

```
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    // Other configs...
    options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
    {
        OnChallenge = async context =>
        {
            // Call this to skip the default logic and avoid using the default response
            context.HandleResponse();

            var httpContext = context.HttpContext;
            var statusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized;

            var routeData = httpContext.GetRouteData();
            var actionContext = new ActionContext(httpContext, routeData, new ActionDescriptor());

            var factory = httpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ProblemDetailsFactory>();
            var problemDetails = factory.CreateProblemDetails(httpContext, statusCode);

            var result = new ObjectResult(problemDetails) { StatusCode = statusCode };
            await result.ExecuteResultAsync(actionContext);
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: This is really flexible solution to respond with any custom ResultObject, such as JsonResult with aditional info, I like it.

Comment: can u pls check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75397637/custom-header-response-when-401-403-eror-in-net-6-7