# Display AuthenticateResult.Fail("Invalid Token Used for Authorisation" ) in custom Authentication for unauthorised user

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-authorization, asp.net-core-authenticationhandler

This is class for Custom Authentiction, but it's not printing message for wrong token key(token key is unique string for each user)
=>AuthenticateResult.Fail("Invalid Token Used for Authorisation") It's just showing Unauthorised 401 status code in postman.
var valtoken = auth.getTokenDetails(token); method returns user details if user with specified token has access to get method of controller else returns null. So for null result I want to return Unauthorised 401 status code with custom message for Get api call

```
namespace CustomAuthDemo
{
/*public class AuthenticationSchemeConstants
{
    public const string BasicAuthScheme = "Basic";
}*/
public class BasicAuthSchemeOptions:AuthenticationSchemeOptions
{

}
public class CustAuthHandler : AuthenticationHandler<BasicAuthSchemeOptions>
{
    private readonly ICustomAuthService auth;
    public CustAuthHandler(IOptionsMonitor<BasicAuthSchemeOptions> options,
        ILoggerFactory logger,
        UrlEncoder encoder,
        ISystemClock clock,
        ICustomAuthService auth):base(options,logger,encoder,clock)
        {
        this.auth = auth;
        }
    protected override async Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
    {
        if (!Request.Headers.ContainsKey("Authorization"))
            return AuthenticateResult.Fail("Unauthorised");

        string authheader = Request.Headers["Authorization"];
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(authheader))
            return AuthenticateResult.Fail("Unauthorised");

        if(!authheader.StartsWith("bearer",StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            return AuthenticateResult.Fail("Unauthorised");

        string token = authheader.Substring("bearer".Length).Trim();
        try
        {
            return ValidateToken(token);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.LogInformation(ex.Message);
            return AuthenticateResult.Fail("Unauthorised");
        }
    }
    private AuthenticateResult ValidateToken(string token)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
            return AuthenticateResult.Fail("Unauthorised");
        var valtoken = auth.getTokenDetails(token);
        if (valtoken == null)
            return AuthenticateResult.Fail("Invalid Token Used for Authorisation");
        var claims = new List<Claim>
        { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name,valtoken.username)};

        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, Scheme.Name);
        var principal = new GenericPrincipal(identity, null);
        var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(principal, Scheme.Name);
        return AuthenticateResult.Success(ticket);
    }
```

Comment: Whether you are using JWT authentication or not? Can you share the related code in the Startup.ConfigureServices method? From your code, it seems that you just change the AuthenticateResult, instead of change the response body. You could refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64082588/asp-core-api-custom-unauthorized-body), change the response body using the AddJwtBearer() method.

Comment: Thanks @ZhiLv, I'm using custom authentication. I got solution to my question. I've overriden HandleChallengeAsync (called when authorisation fails for a particular http request) in my CustomAuthenticationHandler and changed response body of unauthorised http request with status code 401 and error message

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just override HandleChallengeAsync method in CustAuthHandler, this method is called Eveytime when authorisation fails, so I've written back a string and 401 status code to response body of my http request which has failed authentication.

```
protected override async Task HandleChallengeAsync(AuthenticationProperties properties)
        {
            
            await base.HandleChallengeAsync(properties);
            Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
            string output = "authentification failed you don't have access to this content";
            await Response.BodyWriter.WriteAsync(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(output));
        
           
        }
```

Comment: Is this the proper way to go? What if there other Status codes and string ouputs? How can you get them to display to the user from code?

Comment: I dont know if this is the proper way, but it works. The output could be sent in the context from the auth method.