# Custom header response when 401 /403 eror in .net 6/7

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt

This is my code:

i am refernce this link:https://stackoverflow.com/a/71170460/7273263

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
                      {
                          options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                          options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                      }).AddJwtBearer(o =>{
                          o.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
                          o.SaveToken = true;
                          o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                          {  ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                             ...other code
                             
                              IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key)
                          };                    
    
                      });
```

Newly Added code:

// Other configs...

```
  o.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                      {
                          OnChallenge = async context =>
                          {
                              // Call this to skip the default logic and avoid using the default response
    
                              var s = context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode;
 //***Here i am getting 200 error response***
                              context.HandleResponse();
    
                              var httpContext = context.HttpContext;
                             
                              var statusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized;
    
                              var routeData = httpContext.GetRouteData();
                              var actionContext = new ActionContext(httpContext, routeData, new ActionDescriptor());
    
                              var factory = httpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ProblemDetailsFactory>();
                              var problemDetails = factory.CreateProblemDetails(httpContext, statusCode);
    
                              var result = new ObjectResult(problemDetails) { StatusCode = statusCode };
                              await result.ExecuteResultAsync(actionContext);
                          }
                      };
```

The above code working fine .. but i need to response with 401 & 403 error How to dynamically add status code based on http code..if i hard coded 401 i am getting result as expected but it should work for 401 & 403 Please let me know is it possible or not

EDIT:

Controler method

```
[Authorize(Permissions.Master.Read)]
```

Comment: i guess ` context.HandleResponse();` must be the first line, like `OnChallenge = async context =>
                          {context.HandleResponse();}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

401 =>OnChallenge

```
OnChallenge = async context =>
               {
                            context.HandleResponse();
    
                            context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
                            context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized;
    
                            await context.Response.WriteAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new ErrorResponse()
                            {
                                Errors = new List<KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<string>>>
                                {
                                    new KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<string>>(nameof(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized),
                                   
                                    new[] { "Your login has expired, please login again" })
                                }
                            }, new JsonSerializerSettings
                            {
                                ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
                            }));
                        }
```

403 => OnForbidden

```
 OnForbidden = async context =>
                    {
                        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
                        context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status403Forbidden;

                        await context.Response.WriteAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new ErrorResponse()
                        {
                            Errors = new List<KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<string>>>
                                {
                                new KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<string>>(nameof(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden),
                                new[] { "Access denied" })
                                }
                        }, new JsonSerializerSettings
                        {
                            ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
                        }));
                    },
```

full code

```
 options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                {
                    OnForbidden = async context =>
                    {
                        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
                        context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status403Forbidden;

                        await context.Response.WriteAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new ErrorResponse()
                        {
                            Errors = new List<KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<string>>>
                                {
                                new KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<string>>(nameof(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden),
                                new[] { "Access denied" })
                                }
                        }, new JsonSerializerSettings
                        {
                            ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
                        }));
                    },

                    OnChallenge = async context =>
                    {
                        context.HandleResponse();

                        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
                        context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized;

                        await context.Response.WriteAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new ErrorResponse()
                        {
                            Errors = new List<KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<string>>>
                            {
                                new KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<string>>(nameof(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized),
                                //new[] { context?.ErrorDescription ?? "Unauthenticated request" })
                                new[] { "Your login has expired, please login again" })
                            }
                        }, new JsonSerializerSettings
                        {
                            ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
                        }));
                    }
                };
```

Comment: Thanks ...is  OnAuthenticationFailed &  OnChallenge  is same  or wats the difference